# Does better satelite propulsion help selling secondary payloads?

Tags: propulsion, cost, inclination-change, smallsat-launcher, secondary-payload

Generally orbital inclination change is said to be (fuel) expensive so everyone is trying to reach their final orbit straight from the launch vehicle.

Small launch vehicles (Rocket Lab etc.) reach exact orbit but are usually more expensive than secondary payloads which are cheaper but have a disadvantage of not being able to get to exactly desired orbit from a big rocket.

Are advancements in satellite propulsion (ion thrusters on Starlinks etc) going to affect small launcher market? Is it cheaper to put propulsion system to a satelite and ride as secondary payload or to buy dedicated small launch?

Comment: Is the question restricted to Earth orbit missions?

Comment: @uhoh Yes I actually meant around Earth but I will not limit the answers to it.

Answer (score 2):

If your propulsion system has a better specific impulse, then you can travel farther from your initial orbit. So as CubeSat/smallsat propulsion systems improve their efficiency, the range of orbits that can be reached while being launched as a secondary payload will be increased. Theoretically, a solar sail has infinite specific impulse and therefore could reach any desired orbit regardless of where it starts.

The counterargument to all this would be time constraints. If you need to be in a certain orbit within a certain amount of time, you would then want to use a cheap dedicated launcher that could put you in your exact desired orbit. While a solar sail could in theory take you from LEO to Earth escape velocity, it would take a very long time. So long, in fact, that the cost of the ground team monitoring the spacecraft for many months/years may eventually outweigh the savings from using a lighter/more efficient propulsion system.

I think there will always be a market for small launchers, but I also think that it will be cheaper to use in-space propulsion to transfer orbits if time constraints permit.